# How to fire onchange event of combobox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have a combobox, How to fire onchange event of the combobox and get a selected value from it.

Here is the Code what i did till now :

```
<select name="g1" id="select_g1">
        <option value="one">one</option>
        <option value="two">two</option>
        <option value="three">three</option>
    </select>

    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $("select_g1").change(function(){
                alert("Handled"); // alert is not fired up ...
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**EDIT :** What if i have more than one combobox :

```
<select name="g2">
<option value="one">one</option>
<option value="two">two</option>
<option value="three">three</option>
</select>
```

**Also disable the value selected in combobox g1 in combobox g2.**

Could anyone please tell me what is wrong with the code.

Comment: You're missing id selector, try
       ` $("#select_g1").change(function(){`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than trying to use the .change event, please try to use the .on event.

You can try to use it as such:

```
$('#select_g1').on('change', function (e) {
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;
    alert(valueSelected);
});
```

See this here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ocrozmkn/

**EDIT :**

With respect to your edited question, you can try the following jQuery :

```
$('select').on('change', function (e) {
    $('select option').prop('disabled', false);
    var optionSelected = $("option:selected", this);
    var valueSelected = this.value;    
    alert(valueSelected);
    $("select option:contains('" + valueSelected + "')").attr("disabled","disabled");
});
```

See this here ->http://jsfiddle.net/ocrozmkn/1/

**Demo for multiple comboboxes**

See here -> http://jsfiddle.net/ocrozmkn/6/

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: +1 for you. this works like charm. One more question to ask related to this. I want to use this jquery script above for multiple combobox. i.e. same script for two or more combobox. Also if 'A' value is selected in 1st Combobox, then it is disabled in other combobox. Is there anyway to do that... For clarification i am editing the question. Please check..

Comment: @k00989 See the edited answer above. I believe this is what you are looking at!!

Comment: Thanks buddy you really helped me. But what if i have multiple combobox with same value. I want to disable them in all comboboxes, once selected. Also can you u refer me some resources for jquery expertise.

Comment: @k00989 This should work if you have multiple comboboxes. However, you'll need to tweak the code a bit in case you want this to work on only a select few of them. See the new fiddle for the demonstration.

Comment: Thanks but the option which i select in combobox g1 and g2 must be disabled in combobox g3. Its not like that... can we use each function in jquery... I am also trying to change the same... I think the fiddle you provided is same...

Comment: @k00989 You will need to tweak the jquery function for that effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63756/discussion-between-k00989-and-satwik-nadkarny).

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>jQuery Autocomplete</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $("#select_g1").on("change",function(){
            alert($(this).val());
        });
    });

</script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <select name="g1" id="select_g1">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
  </select>



    </body>

    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this :

```
<form class="demo">
<select name="g1" id="select_g1">
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
    <option value="three">three</option>
</select>
</form>

<script>
 $("#select_g1").change(function () {
    var res = this.value;
    alert(res);
   //OR
    alert(this.value);
    });
</script>
```